# Alpha Beta Pruning with Recursion Schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, recursion-schemes, comonad

I'm trying to get more proficient with recursion schemes as they have so far been really helpful for turning gnarly explicit recursion code into something less spike-y. One of the other tools I tend to reach for when implementing algorithms that can get really confusing with explicit recursion is monad transformers / mutability. Ideally I'd like to get comfortable enough with recursion schemes such that I can ditch statefulness altogether. An example of an algorithm I'd still reach for the transformers for is minimax with alpha beta pruning. I did normal minimax with a catamorphism and minimax f-algebra (`data MinimaxF a f = MMResult a | MMState [f] Bool`), but I wasn't sure how I could extend this to do alpha beta pruning. I thought maybe I could use histomorphism, or maybe there was some custom solution with comonads, but I didn't know how to approach trying a solution using either technique.

In addition to a version of alpha beta pruning with recursion schemes any general advice you have about tackling similar problems would be much appreciated. For example I've had trouble applying recursion schemes to algorithms like Dijkstra that usually are implemented in an imperative fashion.

Comment: re: Dijkstra; if you haven't read the [fgl paper](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf), I highly recommend it.

Comment: I think this question would be better if it included your existing minimax solution without alpha beta pruning.

Comment: Does the `Bool` represent the current player?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alpha-beta can be seen as an instance of minimax, where `min` and `max` are instantiated using a well-chosen lattice. [Full gist](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/5f50e4bc7ce1394f59d17fe766df9e4b).

We represent games as a tree, where each internal node is a position in the game, waiting for a designated player to pick a move to a child node, and each leaf is a final position with its score, or value.

```hs
-- | At every step, either the game ended with a value/score,
-- or one of the players is to play.
data GameF a r = Value a | Play Player (NonEmpty r)
 deriving Functor
type Game a = Fix (GameF a)

-- | One player wants to maximize the score,
-- the other wants to minimize the score.
data Player = Mini | Maxi
```

`minimax` will work on any lattice, defined by the following class:

```
class Lattice l where
  inf, sup :: l -> l -> l
```

The `Lattice` class is more general than `Ord`: and `Ord` instance is a `Lattice` with decidable equality (`Eq`). If we could redefine `Ord`, then it would be appropriate to add `Lattice` as a superclass. But here a newtype will have to do:

```
-- The Lattice induced by an Ord
newtype Order a = Order { unOrder :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Ord a => Lattice (Order a) where
  inf = min
  sup = max
```

Here's minimax. It is parameterized by an embedding `leaf :: a -> l` of final values to the chosen lattice. One player maximizes the embedded value, the other player minimizes it.

```
-- | Generalized minimax
gminimax :: Lattice l => (a -> l) -> Game a -> l
gminimax leaf = cata minimaxF where
  minimaxF (Value x) = leaf x
  minimaxF (Play p xs) = foldr1 (lopti p) xs

lopti :: Lattice l => Player -> l -> l -> l
lopti Mini = inf
lopti Maxi = sup
```

The "regular" minimax uses the scores of the game directly as the lattice:

```
minimax :: Ord a => Game a -> a
minimax = unOrder . gminimax Order
```

For alpha-beta pruning, the idea is that we can keep track of some bounds on the optimal score, and this allows us to short-circuit the search. So the search is to be parameterized by that interval `(alpha, beta)`. This leads us to a lattice of functions `Interval a -> a`:

```
newtype Pruning a = Pruning { unPruning :: Interval a -> a }
```

An interval can be represented by `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` to allow either side to be unbounded. But we shall use better named types for clarity, and also to leverage a different `Ord` instance on each side:

```
type Interval a = (WithBot a, WithTop a)
data WithBot a = Bot | NoBot a deriving (Eq, Ord)
data WithTop a = NoTop a | Top deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

We will require that we can only construct `Pruning f` if `f` satisfies `clamp i (f i) = clamp i (f (Bot, Top))`, where `clamp` is defined below. That way, `f` is a search algorithm which may shortcircuit if it learns that its result lies outside of the interval, without having to find the exact result.

```hs
clamp :: Ord a => Interval a -> a -> a
clamp (l, r) = clampBot l . clampTop r

clampBot :: Ord a => WithBot a -> a -> a
clampBot Bot x = x
clampBot (NoBot y) x = max y x

clampTop :: Ord a => WithTop a -> a -> a
clampTop Top x = x
clampTop (NoTop y) x = min y x
```

Functions form a lattice by pointwise lifting. And when we consider only functions satisfying `clamp i (f i) = clamp i (f (Bot, Top))` and equate them modulo a suitable equivalence relation (`Pruning f = Pruning g` if `clamp <*> f = clamp <*> g`), a short-circuiting definition of the lattice becomes possible.

The `inf` of two functions `l` and `r`, given an interval `i = (alpha, beta)`, first runs `l (alpha, beta)` to obtain a value `vl`.
If `vl <= alpha`, then it must be `clamp i vl == alpha == clamp i (min vl (r i))` so we can stop and return `vl` without looking at `r`. Otherwise, we run `r`, knowing that the final result is not going to be more than `vl` so we can also update the upper bound passed to `r`. `sup` is defined symmetrically.

```
instance Ord a => Lattice (Pruning a) where
  inf l r = Pruning \(alpha, beta) ->
    let vl = unPruning l (alpha, beta) in
    if NoBot vl <= alpha then vl else min vl (unPruning r (alpha, min (NoTop vl) beta))

  sup l r = Pruning \(alpha, beta) ->
    let vl = unPruning l (alpha, beta) in
    if beta <= NoTop vl then vl else max vl (unPruning r (max (NoBot vl) alpha, beta))
```

Thus we obtain alpha-beta as an instance of minimax. Once the lattice above is defined, we only need some simple wrapping and unwrapping.

```
alphabeta :: Ord a => Game a -> a
alphabeta = runPruning . gminimax constPruning

constPruning :: a -> Pruning a
constPruning = Pruning . const

runPruning :: Pruning a -> a
runPruning f = unPruning f (Bot, Top)
```

If all goes well, `alphabeta` and `minimax` should have the same result:

```
main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck \g -> minimax g === alphabeta (g :: Game Int)
```

Comment: What the heck, this is amazing. Is this observation (that you can generalize minimax to lattices and get alpha-beta for free from it) a standard one? (If so, why are the usual explanations of alpha-beta pruning made so frickin' complicated when they could just be this???)

Comment: idk. Maybe this could be the start of at least a functional pearl. I share your confusion. When researching for this answer, I found that the wikipedia entry on alpha-beta pruning is a mess, and the little code there leaves more questions than it answers...